# $_GET pega valor do ID ou do name?

Tags: php, html, post, get

O `$_GET`, ou até mesmo o `$_POST`, pegam valores do ID do `input` ou do `name`?

```
<form action="#" method="get" name="meuForm">

<input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" value="Teste">

<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="Teste">

</form>
```

Quando fizermos isso: `$_GET['nome']` ou `$_GET['email']`, ele vai puxar do `ID="nome"` ou do `name="nome"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normalmente vem do `name`, é ele que o formulário usa para codificar na mensagem ou o URL de requisição ao servidor, e portanto é isto que o PHP receberá.

Note que o PHP não sabe o que vem, de onde vem, ele não entende HTML, JS, nada disso. O PHP pega a comunicação HTTP, lendo o URL no caso do `$_GET`, ou lendo a requisição no caso do `$_POST`.

Inclusive você pode fazer uma requisição que não use o HTML como base. Pode fazer com JS no *browser* ou por uma aplicação que sequer sabe o que é HTML. Então nada impede de passar outra coisa. Mas o padrão do HTML é o `name`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ah, entendi, o PHP so puxa da URL! Não tinha pensado nisso.

Comment: Da URL se a requisição for GET, @LucasCarvalho. Se for POST é do corpo da requisição.

Answer (score 0):

O $_GET e o $_POST pegam os valores do name, para pegar valores via id, vc deve utilizar javascript ou jquery.

Comment: No caso meio que o bigown me explicou, ai não seria do name, e sim da URL. Mas obrigado pela resposta também!